# Wordpress Migration to 1and1.com didn't copy plugin styles

Tags: wordpress

My issue is that the styling that was done to the website is completely missing. The Widgets are also not showing up. When I go into the backend, they are all in place. IF I add a NEW widget, it does show up. So I have something wrong in the .sql file is my guess.

I did notice in my database that I still have a file structure like this: `/home/cyndeetg/public_html/mywebsite.com/wp.......`

I've seen how on other tutorials to remove the "cyndeetg" part. it's easy to figure out on there, but the way 1and1 does it, it's not clear to me how to find out the new name. The database on the other ones was something like cyndeetg_213 and all you had to do was replace cyndeetg with the new database name in your database, but 1and1.com database names are made completely different and are something like dbw12ed1d214  (no underscore). I think this is what I need to fix but am still not sure. Any thoughts?.

[Original Div site](http://www.asapwv.cyndeeadkinsdesign.com/)
[New live site](http://www.asapwv.com/)

Comment: I dropped all of the dp tables, and re-uploaded it. Installed a plugin called WP Migrate DB, used it and it gave me (what I think) is the correct address for my files. It still hasn't fixed the issue with the plugins styling still missing and some of the widgets styling missing.

Answer (score 0):

I did another dump and restore since I learned that the way Wordpress codes where the data is for the plugins data is strange. I used a simple find and replace app called "Velvet Blues Update URLs" just to update the links and the locations of images/documents and all is working perfectly. I hope this helps someone else if they come across this!